# Cannot find Proximity Beacon API at https://console.developers.google.com/

Tags: beacon, google-beacon-platform

I'm trying to enable **Proximity Beacon API** at https://console.developers.google.com/. But When  I was trying to search this API, it's showing no result found. Can someone help to get this API enable for my project.
[image]

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this? I am also facing the same issue. Not able to find the Google Proximity Beacon API in the console.